# adding image to has_many relationship moves image to assets folder

Tags: orm, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a list of images associated with an object. using a DataExtension to add a has_many relationship. The images are stored in subdirectories of Assets and I add them with the sync folders button in the cms. However when I add the relationship the Image is moved to the assets directory. How do I create the relation without moving the file? why does this happen?

```
class GroupExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $has_many = array('ImageGroup' => 'Image');

    function addImage($img)
    {
        $this->owner->ImageGroup()->add($img);
        $this->owner->write();
        $img->write();
    }
}
```

Comment: More than likely the culprit here is $img->write(); Take a look inside this function to see if there are any directory operations, such as storing the file in the default directory. If this is the case, make sure the image is set to save in your specified sub directory before this write function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `$many_many` relationship for this.

`$has_many` would only work if there was an associated `$has_one` on `Image`, and although in principle you could do this with a sub-class of `Image`, in practise using `$many_many` will work much better.

If you use `$many_many`, you won't need the `$img->write()` call.